# $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}}(\mathcal{M,N}) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{B}}(\mathcal{M} \otimes_{\mathcal{A}} \mathcal{B,N})$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $\varphi \colon \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ be a morphism of sheaves of ring.
Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a $\mathcal{A}$-module and $\mathcal{N}$ be a $\mathcal{B}$-module.
Do we have $$ \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}}(\mathcal{M}, \mathcal{N}) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{B}}(\mathcal{M} \otimes_{\mathcal{A}} \mathcal{B}, \mathcal{N})? $$

Comment: 1. This is the hom-tensor adjunction. 2. Right now, your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Sebastiano the correct command to give a well-formatted $\operatorname{Hom}$ is \operatorname{Hom}. It produces better spacing than using \mathrm when used in this context.

Comment: @KReiser Yes, I know this approach. But I have just copied the \mathrm of the question. Now changed it.

Comment: @Sebastiano that title was not very good - titles should be informative, and "Algebraic geometry: a morphism" could refer to just about anything. I recognize that there's a difficulty here because of character limits for titles, but your edit made the question worse and that should be avoided. I've fixed the title for now.

Comment: @KReiser No problem. Thank you for your collaboration.